# Is it possible to create dynamic Typescript type based on some model?

Tags: angular, typescript

Consider I have an `Address` interface model:

```
interface AddressModel {
  street: string | null;
  streetNumber: string | null;
  postalCode: string | null;
  city: string | null;
  country: string | null;
  latitude: number | null;
  longitude: number | null;
}
```

As Angular 14 released, I would like to create a typed form group based on `AddressModel`, where the key would be name of the form control and the value is a form control itself with the perspective value of the key, so the result model would be:

```
interface AddressFormGroup {
  street: FormControl<string | null>;
  streetNumber: FormControl<string | null>;
  postalCode: FormControl<string | null>;
  city: FormControl<string | null>;
  country: FormControl<string | null>;
  latitude: FormControl<number | null>;
  longitude: FormControl<number | null>;
}
```

I know this can be done creating the model manually but maybe Typescript has features to automate this process?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A simple [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) will do this for you.

```
type ToFormControl<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]: FormControl<T[K]>
}
```

```
type AddressFormGroup = ToFormControl<AddressModel>

// type AddressFormGroup = {
//     street: FormControl<string | null>;
//     streetNumber: FormControl<string | null>;
//     postalCode: FormControl<string | null>;
//     city: FormControl<string | null>;
//     country: FormControl<...>;
//     latitude: FormControl<...>;
//     longitude: FormControl<...>;
// }
```

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKFEsFsAcHsCcAuACA3sgYgyBhWA7ReWAG2QF9kAzYyZAcgAEBDfAcwFcTn4B6K7AGd6oCIQCm8KswDG45AEEAJkvjjBggLKwl4sqlDJkgouPGIAXMaLh2yAD7J8XEgG5D1teYByHSACNJKxN4WzYHJxd3ECM4E2YSPF1gmztHZxI3DxlwRABPFNC0yMzooxlYDkJ4As8wiIysmORuRFyOZMiAyQaojxICNnbO5274XtLQclEQfOh5ABVYLHhcAiJSAB4FgD5kAF40DyMAbQBpZFtkAGtxPNgqZAWAXSsVteqthfPnnamZubyZSqdSCd4AcWIHGgByey2weE%20JE2wLUGm0uhIfxAvF4yEBihUaLB2EhlRhhwMOLxRiMITMlkwCPWxGRIXq6RcO2iuNpdNMPj8gXgb2ZSM27OKjW5oF5fLiiASSXEotWiI2bNS4U5mRl1L5yBy%20VVHw1Eq1EyxPJptIqVSItXe6tZmwAdO69XLaa1hiqmWqWVt3a7PTajAN2L6Tc6gx7rRQgA)